# SceneKit: export mesh that has been imported from STL results in garbage

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, apple-model-io

I am using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/epologee/7373ea371812e8facd5a7a00e6b80d70) to import a binary STL 3d mesh into a SCNNode, which works fine (I can view the mesh in a SCNView and it looks good).

However, if I try to export the (unchanged) mesh using either `MDLAsset.export(to: url)` or `SCNScene.write(to: url)` to an STL or OBJ file, the resulting mesh is broken.

If I load the example `ship.scn` scene and then export to STL, everything looks good.
This makes me think that there must be something wrong about how the above mentioned gist creates the SCNNode, but I can't figure out what it is.

Actual model:
[image]
Result of STL/OBJ export:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The SCNGeometryElement's constructor allows to pass nil for the indices data. While this is fine for showing the mesh in a scene, at least the export functionality and probably other parts of the framework rely on the data being populated - which, contrary to what one would expect - isn't done by the constructor automatically. So you need to do that yourself. Luckily there is another constructor which makes this easier:

```
let indices = [UInt32](0..<UInt32(trianglesCounted * 3))
let countedTriangles = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
```